# `require': no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

Trying to get ruby on rails 1.8.7 working on windows but when i start rails server i get this error:

`require': no such file to load -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

I have tried copying the 3 files and putting them in ruby/bin but it doesnt help as mentioned at the bottom of this post: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/216270

Any ideas?

Comment: What platform are you on? Have you installed the `sqlite3` gem successfully?

Comment: by platform u mean os? windows 7

Comment: What about installing the gem?

Comment: i think so... it says: Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sqlite3-1.3.3-x86-mingw32...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution on this post's comments http://www.shaunambrose.com/2010/08/05/how-to-fix-a-sqlite3-dll-missing-error-message-in-ruby-on-rails/comment-page-1/#comment-15965

"The problem seems to be that the sqlite3 gem is compiled with version 3.7.3. I downloaded and set up version 3.7.3 instead and it now works just fine."

Get it here: http://www.sqlite.org/sqlitedll-3_7_3.zip

Comment: Where did you add the sqlite3.dll?

Comment: Sorry @EduardoWada I cannot remember, I'm on mac now. Did you find out?

Answer (score 2):

Uncomment the line “gem ‘sqlite3-ruby’, :require => ‘sqlite3′” and comment the line “gem ‘sqlite3′” in your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

While I was trying to play around Amazon Linux, I too faced the same

> "/usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
>   (LoadError)"

Since everything was already setup on my local, I tried debugging.

The issue apparently is the library is missing in

> /usr/local/share/ruby/gems/2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10/lib/sqlite3/

If you go to this path, you will see that sqlite3_native.so is not present.

What I did was simply, ran a `locate sqlite3_native.so` and copied it to the location.

I faced the same issue with all other libraries in Amazon Linux, including nokogiri and nodejs.